# Add stacked items to table layout panel in visual studio .net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I've been trying to add items to my tableLayoutPanel in visual studio .net application, but it seems that they just get replaced in the first item position.

```
Public rows As Integer = 0
Public CAIList As New List(Of String)
Public p As New Panel()
Public p2 As New Panel()
Public tb As New Label()
Public tb2 As New Label()
Public Sub addCAI()    
If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_analyst.Text) Then
  CAIList.Add(txt_analyst.Text)
  tb.Text = txt_analyst.Text
  tb2.Text = "OUTDATED"
  p.Controls.Add(tb)
  p2.Controls.Add(tb2)
  p.AutoSize = True
  p2.AutoSize = True
  MainMenu.table_analysts.Controls.Add(p, 0, rows)
  MainMenu.table_analysts.Controls.Add(p2, 1, rows)
  rows = rows + 1
Else
   MessageBox.Show("Cannot add empty Analyst")
End If
```

At first I thought that the problem was that "Rows" kept being set to 0, but then I debugged it and it increments alright. (0,1,2,3....)

IT SHOULD WORK!!! it's driving me crazy.

Comment: It's not clear from your code...but you can't add the same panels into different rows.  They will simply be removed from their last position and moved to the new position.  If your intention was to have multiple sets of panels, then you need to create a **new** Panel and associated controls for **each** row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the post how many rows are in your TableLayoutPanel, but you have to make sure the rows exist in order to add those controls.  I don't think an exception is thrown when trying to add controls to a non-existent cell:

```
If MainMenu.table_analysts.RowStyles.Count - 1 < rows Then
  MainMenu.table_analysts.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent))
End If

For i As Integer = 0 to rows
  MainMenu.table_analysts.RowStyles(i).Height = 1 / rows
Next

MainMenu.table_analysts.Controls.Add(p, 0, rows)
MainMenu.table_analysts.Controls.Add(p2, 1, rows)
rows = rows + 1
```

Also, make sure the cells are empty before adding the panels by disposing any existing controls.  Only one control is allowed per cell.

As Idle_Mind commented, make sure you also create "new" controls when you call your routine:

```
Public Sub addCAI()
  If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_analyst.Text) Then
    Dim p As New Panel()
    Dim p2 As New Panel()
    Dim tb As New Label()
    Dim tb2 As New Label()
```

Comment: Awesome! it works, but the reason I put the PUBLIC variables before was because I needed to refresh the status of the analysts, this was done by re-creating the rows using the list from CAIList, and getting the text on the 2nd column from a txt file with streamReader. It worked as a charm, but only when I was able to call the controls from outside the Sub.

Comment: It says I still can't because of my reputation (below 15). Thanks!

Comment: @FerMelon See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/162993).  It doesn't say anything about a reputation limit, so you should get 2 points when you click accept.  Hope that helps.